# Google Oauth2 authentication returns "Required parameter is missing: grant_type"

Tags: java, google-oauth

I am trying to get the refresh token from Google in order to access Google drive. So Far I have managed to create a page in google app engine which redirects me to authentication page and I am able to get the code. The url address for getting there is

```
Window.Location.assign("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=profile&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8888/oauth2manager/redirect&response_type=code&client_id=1058171155388-hg2akr2idan7c2kvdam9b89vptcjai8i.apps.googleusercontent.com");
```

I then get redirected to the /oauth2manager/redirect servlet and get the code inside the doPost method

```
String code = request.getParameter("code");
```

My problem is that I cannot proceed as  I constantly get the above error "Required parameter is missing: grant_type" I have tried restclient wiztools, RestEasy firefox extension even curl.
here is my Curl script

```
 #!/bin/bash
$code= "4/E7i1aKu4C-Pf23-8hY4Y8OBe9IBZ.wtKglnd8-CMdOl05ti8ZT3aNPWw7igI";
curl -v --data "code="+$code+"&client_id=1058171155388-hg2akr2idan7c2kvdam9b89vptcjai8i@developer.gserviceaccount.com&client_secret=JHXTAT4UWwsNaMgm******&redirect_uri= http://127.0.0.1:8888/oauth2manager/redirect&grant_type=authorization_code" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

How can this be solved? I am a total newbie at this.

Answer (score 0):

I think your mixing Oauth types.  The code you are using is for normal Oauth2.  But your clientid is for a service account.

Normal Oauth2 will ask a user if they want to allow your access to their data.  A service account is for allowing others access to the application's data, there is no permission request with a service account.

Link to the documentation for service accounts. [Service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of that. I will try it and see how it goes